# Separate frontend assets from admin assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I'd like some feedback if possible. I have a rails app with this folder structure

```
rails
- app
-- controllers
--- admin
--- front
```

So basically I have cotrollers on both `front` and `admin` namespace. However the assets have the default setting at the moment, like this

```
assets
- stylesheets
- javascripts
```

so `application.scss` loads all css for both front and admin

```
*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

How can I specify the front layout to load only assets required for the frontend (and not admin) and the admin layout to load only the admin assets and not front assets?

Comment: May not be cleanest way, but you could always use two different layouts and reference the necessary assets that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two manifest files (instead of using the default `application.js`/`application.scss`) and include them in different layouts (one for `front` and one for `admin`).

For example, you could you use this folder structure:

```
assets
- javascripts
-- admin
-- front
- stylesheets
-- admin
-- front
- admin.scss
- front.scss
```

Inside each admin/front folder you can add the specific styles/scripts needed, then ensure your manifest files look like this (only showing styles manifests, same goes for scripts):

admin.scss

```
/*
 * Manifest file for admin styles, to be compiled into admin.scss
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./admin
 */
```

front.scss

```
/*
 * Manifest file for front styles, to be compiled into front.scss
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./front
 */
```

Now you must create your layouts (in `app/views/layouts`):

admin.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ... title and metas
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'admin' %>
  </head>
  <body>
     ... layout content
  </body>
<html>
```

front.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ... title and metas
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'front', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'front' %>
  </head>
  <body>
     ... layout content
  </body>
<html>
```

Finally, you must add your manifest files in `config/initializers/assets.rb` to be precompiled:

```
... some code
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(admin.scss front.scss)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(admin.js front.js)
```

Now you only need to use the desired layout (`admin.html.erb` or `front.html.erb`)
when rendering your views.

Comment: Hi, i removed the layouts/application.html.erb and create (admin.html.erb and front.html.erb) in the same place. I added the manifest files in assets.rb too, but when i try to access my front, the front.html.erb doesn't load.